Does the mean of multiple measurements of one sensor reduce the sensor error, in the case of a data-logged K-type thermocouple?
I'm doing an experiment to measure steady-state heat transfer conditions. I have a hot plate connected to a power supply which supplies a constant current (~1.880A in this run). It is very precise, and the voltage only varies minimally with the changing resistance of the internal resistive element (flat nichrome wire, <0.1% drift).
One of my runs produced this result, here shown a hot plate temperature (orange) and the lab air temperature (pink). Measurements done with K-type thermocouples and logged with the MCR-4TC data logger:

The room temperature measures between 23.1ºC to 23.4ºC. The hot plate, 66.7ºC to 67.4ºC.
If I take 30-minute chunks and calculate the average and twice the std deviation, I get:
+--------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|                    Time                    |    RoomAir     |    HotPlate    |
+--------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2024-04-04 03:00:00 to 2024-04-04 03:30:00 | 23.22 +/- 0.07 | 67.07 +/- 0.21 |
| 2024-04-04 03:30:00 to 2024-04-04 04:00:00 | 23.22 +/- 0.08 | 67.05 +/- 0.23 |
| 2024-04-04 04:00:00 to 2024-04-04 04:30:00 | 23.22 +/- 0.07 | 67.03 +/- 0.23 |
| 2024-04-04 04:30:00 to 2024-04-04 05:00:00 | 23.22 +/- 0.08 | 67.05 +/- 0.22 |
| 2024-04-04 05:00:00 to 2024-04-04 05:30:00 | 23.22 +/- 0.09 | 67.05 +/- 0.23 |
| 2024-04-04 05:30:00 to 2024-04-04 06:00:00 | 23.22 +/- 0.09 | 67.04 +/- 0.22 |
| 2024-04-04 06:00:00 to 2024-04-04 06:30:00 | 23.25 +/- 0.10 | 67.05 +/- 0.24 |
| 2024-04-04 06:30:00 to 2024-04-04 07:00:00 | 23.26 +/- 0.10 | 67.05 +/- 0.22 |
+--------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+

Looking at these numbers, it appears that the system is in a steady-state around 67.05ºC bottom temp, 23.22ºC lab temp .
What's the physical reality of the system? Is it actually steady at a state of ~67ºC, and I'm seeing random noise in the measurements? Or is the hot plate really ranging across 0.7ºC, which the range merely centered around ~67.05ºC and ~95% of the range within +/- 0.2ºC?
I just find it odd that the temperature can be swinging so much at what appears to be a steady state, for example here the temp appears go to up +0.5ºC within 45 seconds:


I see some bouncing around of the least significant bit. You would need to check the specs of your data logger for its noise and precision. And, of course, consider how the hot plate works (constant heat, PID control, etc.).

@JonCuster: Ty for the tip. Type K resolution: +/- (0.5ºC + 0.3% reading). For ~67ºC that gives +/- 0.701ºC error!
Does averaging multiple readings result in a more accurate temperature? If the noise were randomly distributed I think it would, but not sure that is the case...

Does the hot plate have a temperature regulating device (automatic resetting thermostat)?

@BobD: I updated the question. It's given a constant current, ~1.880A or so; no temperature-regulating device.
